# Почему не работает ngIf

Tags: typescript, angular

Делаю в шаблоне проверку

```
<div *ngIf="product.info && product.info !== undefined">
  <quill-view-html [content]="product.info"></quill-view-html>
</div>
```

И при запуске IDEA выдает ошибку

```
error TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Разве этой проверки не достаточно?

Comment: В таких случаях лучше писать так `*ngIf="product?.info`. optionalChaining упростит синтаксис и скорее всего решит вашу проблему. И возможно, что у вас в компоненте `quill-view-html` на вход параметр `content` может принимать только строку. проверьте там тип.

Comment: в том то и дело, что content может принимать только строку.
А вариант *ngIf="product?.info не помог

Comment: А что мешает убрать проверку на `!== undefined`, потому что получается, если есть строка, то она не undefined и не пустая строка. В остальном случае будет false

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось решить проблему двумя способами.
так:

```
<div *ngIf="product.info && product.info != undefined">
  <quill-view-html [content]="product.info"></quill-view-html>
</div>
```

или так

```
<div *ngIf="product.info && product.info.length > 0">
  <quill-view-html [content]="product.info"></quill-view-html>
</div>
```